# Как отсортировать массив

Tags: javascript

У меня есть массив

```
my_arr = [["ну", 2], ["короче", 2], ["кстати", 2], ["скажем", 1], ["блин", 8], ["реально", 1], ["собственно", 1], ["фактически", 2], ["ладно", 2], ["походу", 1], ["допустим", 2], ["получается", 1]]
```

Как его отсортировать по убыванию?

Comment: Прочитайте про метод sort и примените его

Comment: я пробую arrayOfParasites.sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1]), но мне надо по убыванию

Comment: тогда поменяй местами эти переменные и всё. т.е. b[1] - a[1]. там же в доках написано что по если колбэк возвращает число отрициательное, то наименьше идёт вправо.

Comment: Благодарю, работает!